# delete specific files with extention in bulk with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to delete files with a specific extension but IT HAS TO TAKE THE USERS INPUT and the script I have does that but it does it one by one but not in bulk and I have honestly been very confused on how to complete this can I get some help on this please I have been struggling, the script below I appreciate all help:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('path'):
    for xml in filenames:
        if xml.lower().endswith('.xml'):
            if input('remove exisiting xml files? y/n: ') == "y":
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, XML))
                print('the file has been deleted succesfully')
    else:
        print('the file has not been deleted')
```

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not asking first the input question once for all the files, and then deleting every file after confirmation? For example:

```
import os

if input('remove exisiting xml files? y/n: ') != "y":
    print('Canceling deleting process')
else:
    print('deleting all xml files')
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('path'):
        for xml in filenames:
            if xml.lower().endswith('.xml'):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, xml)
                print(f'deleting file {file_path}')
                os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to ask for user input right at the beginning:

```
if input('remove exisiting xml files? y/n: ') == "y":
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('path'):
        for xml in filenames:
            if xml.lower().endswith('.xml'):
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, xml))  # notice the lowercase variable name. Python is case-sensitive
else:
    print('the file has not been deleted')
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!